# how to import some content to a new site?

Tags: 6

**site A** powered by drupal 6 whch has a content type `news`. there are many articles under it.

**site B** is a new site. which powered by drupal 6 too. now i only want to import those articles in **site A** to **site B**. how do i do? thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The [deploy](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) module can move nodes between Drupal sites.  For advanced uses there's also [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate).

Answer (score 0):

Export the content from site A using views + http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus to create a CSV of all the news items you need.

Then use the feeds module to import the CSV into site B.

Both modules have a good amount of documentation.

Thanks
Reece